# JList addition to Object.toString

Tags: java, swing

I have an Object class lets say shipment. That shipment is shown with a toString that is very commonly used in JLists but there is one single JList where I need more values of that shipement to be shown (like date,buyer..).Can I do an @Override toString rigth here and only in this "for" cycle?

```
for(Shipement s: listShipement){
    model.addElement(s);
}
```

Can I override it here?I know its stupid but I need it for this one.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Do you want to add a special `toString` implementation to some object instances of an existing class (that you cannot modify)? Please explain in more detail and give some more context (what is it that you actually need to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but there is one single JList where I need more values of that shipement to be shown

Two options:

a) set a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) on the list, that produces the output you want. You need to implement that class yourself, but you can extend [`DefaultListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html].).

b) wrap the list entries into some other class, that has a `toString` method that does what you need.